# Replicating exact Word document format with RMarkdown

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

In R Markdown, one can out generate a word document with the YAML header `output: word_document`. This produces a very basic Word document. The basic appearance of this document can be customized by providing a reference template as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-template.html).

However, I frequently produce Word documents of an exact template. Many of the journals I commonly submit to have a particular template they require submission in.

Is there anyway that I can more specifically customize how R Markdown converts to a Word document? Perhaps with additional custom YAML arguments? And also with the ability to calculate counts or other items from the `.Rmd` file, such as a word count or reference count? For example, ideally I would be able to provide a YAML like so:

```
---
title: How to make a custom Word template
authors:
    - name: "John Doe, M.D."
      affiliation: University of Texas
    - name: "Jane Doe, M.D."
      affiliation: University of California
    - name: "Foo Bar, M.D."
      affiliation: University of Texas
output: word_document
bibliography: bibliography.bib
keywords: word, pandoc, r
abstract: |
    blah blah blah blah blah
---
```

And it produce an output like:

---

## How to make a custom Word template

John Doe, M.D.<sup>1</sup>, Jane Doe, M.D.<sup>1</sup>, Foo Bar, M.D.<sup>1,2</sup>

1. University of Texas
2. University of California

**ABSTRACT WORD COUNT**: 4
**MANUSCRIPT WORD COUNT**: 500
**NUMBER OF TABLES**: 3
**NUMBER OF FIGURES**: 5
**KEYWORDS**: word, pandoc, R
**NUMBER OF REFERENCES**: 10

### Abstract

Blah blah blah blah.

---

What is the - or is there a - better way to wield control over the Word document output in Rmarkdown in order to produce very specific output templates?

Answer (score 1):

A true template system for docx output is currently not available; see the pandoc issues [#7256](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7256) and [#3109](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3109) for details.

However, you can do what you need by using a pandoc [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters) ([R Markdown cookbook section on Lua filters](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html)). E.g., for the authors and affiliations, see the [author-info-blocks](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/author-info-blocks) filter. It would be possible to extend the filter such that it suits your needs, but it'd be not as straight-forward as one might wish.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like Lua filters is the way to go right now.