# How to add different items to the YAML Rmarkdown pdf

Tags: yaml, r-markdown

I am using this code for the first page of my Rmarkdown. I want to add :

- - name of the course
- name of the tutor
- number of the words
- number of graphs
- number of tables

This is my code :

```
title: "Title of report "
author:  "my name"
Email: "my email"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_width: 4.5
    fig_height: 3
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}
    - \onehalfspacing
date: '2022-07-06'
csl: chicago-author-date.csl
bibliography: bib1.bib
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replicating exact Word document format with RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741318/replicating-exact-word-document-format-with-rmarkdown)

Comment: Maybe something similar to [metadata in Rmarkdown YAML](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/document-metadata.html)? Might want to specify if you are using Bookdown? seems Bookdown has more control over numbering your graphs/tables/words. [Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733738/7401037)